# Are the Trade Federation and Separatist armies the same?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

It seems that both armies are made up of battle droids.

**Are they the same?**

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Separatist_Droid_Army vs http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Trade_Federation_Droid_Army

Comment: Will you kindly answer me in a sentence please. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No

The Trade Federation Army from *Episode I* added the support of the Techno Union army and others to create the larger Separatist Army. **The Trade Federation Army - a stand-alone army in *Episode I* - becomes a subset of the larger Separatist Army in *Episode II.***

Obi-Wan Kenobi witnesses the meeting between Separatist leaders to discuss Dooku's treaty and the formation of the Separatist Army, which they refer to as "the finest army in the galaxy."

Comment: So,Are they connected or related or what?

Comment: @augustine08282011 - It sounds like the Trade Federation Army is a subset of the Separatist Army.

Comment: yes I notice that when the trade federation army was defeated in the phantom menace. In the next sequel,attack of the clones the trade federation army joins the separatist army.

Comment: Correct. Does that sufficiently answer your question?

Comment: Yes, theironcheek. Thank you for answering

Comment: @augustine08282011 - Awesome. If no one else posts a better answer, feel free to click the checkmark at the top of my answer to mark it as the Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hell @augustine08282011,

good question here. First off, the answer by @TheIronCheek is correct, I just noticed you didn't hit the "question answered" yet, hence why I believe you're looking for more details which I'm willing to give you:

**Spoiler warning from this point onwards:**

Darth Sidious makes up with the Trade Federation prior to the events as displayed in Episode I. He directs them to do his bidding and promises, in exchange for this, that they'll end up with advantages, supporting their business. Whilst having all those battle droids and Lucrehulk spaceships, they are not fit to fight a war against the republic solely on their own.
Thats why Darth Sidious sends out Count Dooku, a former Jedi, to form the separatist movement - commonly known as the CIS:

C - Confederacy
(of)
I - Independent
S - Systems

Hes doing this by influencing systems to break with the republic and by promising positive results to the main factions, to actually form this movement. The main factions as by the start of the war are:

Trade Federation (Ressources)
Techno Union (Technology, such as the super battle droids)
Banking Clan (Money)

along with all the minor planetary / system bodies and parties, they form the CIS.

So the forces of the Trade Federation ARE part of the CIS forces, but make not up the entire CIS forces - so your answer is **no, they are not the same thing, one is part of the other.**

Answer (score 0):

All the systems in the *CIS* contribute to the *CIS* armada, ex. super tanks from Baktoid Armour Workshop (on Geonosis).

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? For example, what is the relationship of the Trade Federation to the CIS?

Comment: I don't understand what baktoid armour workshop is